# Where do I put my favicon?

Tags: html, apache, apache2, raspberry-pi

I have been searching everywhere for where to put my favicon. Currently I have it in my document root(/var/www/favicon.ico)(I am using apache2 on ubuntu), and my code looks like this in my index.html (The only other file in /var/www)

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/var/www/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Is it supposed to go in my ServerRoot?
I have tried clearing chromes cache, but every time all I get is the same freenom (My domain name provider's) favicon. When I go to my website http://www.website.cf/favicon.ico, I can see their 16*16 icon.

Sorry if I have botched some terminology, I'm a linux/apache newb. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in your web root. This is the default location and web browsers will always look there first. Then you won't need to use a `<link>` tag but if you do you would use:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Based on your cpode sample above that would be in your `/var/www` directory.

Comment: For some reason I still cannot see my favicon, even though I have my favicon.ico in my /var/www directory.

Comment: Try clearing your cache and trying it in a different browser.

Comment: Still no luck. Is it possible that my domain name provider is not allowing me to use my own?

Comment: No. They have no control over that.

Comment: Here, you can try to access my site. I have the icon set to the same as reddits atm. http://www.brianhotopp.cf

Comment: [I can see it just fine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rplly18qp86i13p/Screenshot%202014-11-05%2020.34.16.png?dl=0)

Comment: The FN? That is the default of my domain name provider. The one I am trying to display is starry night

Comment: I had to restart the Apache service on my own web server for the favicon to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Put the fevicon icon in root directory(Default Location of website) and use this code:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
 <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>`